# Maximal $L^p$-regularity of Laplace-Beltrami operator $\Delta$ on closed manifold

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, heat-equation, semigroup-of-operators, functional-calculus

It's well-known that the Dirichlet Laplacian $\Delta$ on flat domain is R-sectorial on $\Sigma_{\pi}$ in $L^p$ space for all $p\in (1,\infty)$.

I'm wondering if the Laplace-Beltrami operator $\Delta$ on closed manifold has the same property?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with $R$-sectorial operators, but it is true that the Laplace-Beltrami operator on closed manifolds is sectorial on $L^p$ for $p\in (1,\infty)$ by an interpolation argument: One can interpolate analyticity on $L^2$ (coming from Hilbert space theory) and strong continuity on $L^1$ to get analyticity on intermediate values of $p$ (that's Stein's interpolation theorem), and then use duality to get analyticity for $p\in (2,\infty)$. Maybe a similar argument also works for $R$-sectoriality?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. R-sectorial just means sectorial and R-boundedness. I have found in the literature that Laplace-Beltrami operator on closed manifolds is R-sectorial in $L^p$ (in the sector $\Sigma_{\pi/2+\epsilon}$) but I want to know if it is R-sectorial in $\Sigma_{\pi}$?